# Have American urban rioters ever looted residences?

Tags: united-states, crime, cities

The current (summer 2020) occurrences of looting and rioting are targeting stores and businesses, so I am wondering if houses and apartments might potentially become targets at some point. In previous American riots (eg 1968, 1992), did looters ever enter residences in the affected cities?

Comment: Welcome to History:Stack Exchange. Thank you for your question, but please consider revising it to be more in line with our community expectations. Like many other stacks, we expect questions to [provide evidence of prior research](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3227/1599). That helps us to understand the question, and avoids our repeating work you've already done.  Our [help] center, and [other stacks](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3224/how-do-i-write-a-good-question) provide additional resources to assist with revisions.

Comment: I don't have sources to back this up so I'm putting it as a comment, not an answer, but consider that many businesses in urban areas have apartments in their upper floors, so just because the looting is confined mostly to commercial districts doesn't mean no residences are being looted.

Comment: NB, all the examples of civil unrest given (1968, 1992, 2020) concerned minority rights, while both examples of looting that we have so far (1849, 1921) were committed against minorities.

Comment: Why go back into history. There were [failed home invasions](https://mckinleypark.news/news/604-looting-arson-attempted-home-invasions-mar-mckinley-park-neighborhood) this weekend.

Comment: My grandfather once owned a mom-and-pop-style movie rental, and because it was in a different state from his house (which he changed later), he had a cot down in the basement and would sometimes sleep in his store.  His business ***was*** one of his residences.  If rioters had come by, hoping to bring justice to "fascist" mega-corporations, they would've instead hurt a mom-and-pop operation and invaded a residence. I have to imagine there are many instances where this has actually happened to someone, which would lend a "yes" to your question.  Businesses and residences are sometimes the same.

Comment: @Panzercrisis Such a residence does not appear as such to the unsuspecting average looter, though

Comment: @CGCampbell There was also at least one _successful_ [arson of a large apartment complex last week](https://www.reuters.com/article/uk-factcheck-fire-building-mn/fact-check-minneapolis-building-on-fire-is-apartment-complex-not-police-precinct-idUSKBN23537D), though it appears that it was still under construction and not occupied yet.

Comment: I don't have a reference I can link, but there was a fire in an apartment building on Coachman Road in Eagan on Friday (May 29), which is probably a 15 drive from [Lake Street](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=htcU0V-g9L4) in Minneapolis which is now ashes.  The Saint Paul Pioneer Press had an article that listed all of the damaged properties on Friday, but I can't seem to find it again.

Comment: With at least [170 damaged properties](https://www.twincities.com/2020/05/28/st-paul-police-responding-to-large-groups-in-midway-area-some-trying-to-steal-items-from-target-store/) and counting, there may never really be a collective tally.  It does appear that the primary targets are businesses, but until the local paper prints a list of some kind, I don't know how it really can be known how many residences were targeted vs businesses.

Comment: @Hagen von Eitzen well of course. they're not exactly thinking about much at all

Comment: @AaronBrick That is true, but when you're alone in your store or your home and a mob breaks in, you are a minority at least temporarily regardless of your skin color.

Answer (score 109):

To pick just one notorious example, 99 years ago to the day, black people's homes were heavily looted by whites in **the Tulsa riots of 1921**. As [this article](http://users.clas.ufl.edu/davidson/Historical%20archaeology%20fall%202015/Week%2015%20Rosewood/Halliburton%201972.pdf) describes, at least 65 looters were arrested. In addition to taking basic goods like sacks of flour, they opened up safes in people's homes to take gold and silver.

EDIT, July 2020: I should have made clear that the looting was not the central aspect of this event. It was a massacre and (as @T.E.D. pointed out in a comment) the total destruction of a prosperous black neighborhood called Greenwood. Excavations of a potential mass grave recently began in Tulsa. [The Washington Post reports](https://www.washingtonpost.com/history/2020/07/13/tulsa-digs-mass-graves-race-massacre-oaklawn-cemetery/)

> Historians believe that as many as 300 black people were killed, and 40 square blocks of what was known as Black Wall Street were destroyed by fire. The destruction included more than 1,250 homes, churches, schools, businesses, a hospital and library.

Comment: Deleted my similar answer and upvoted. The neighborhood was also **burned to the ground.** The estimate was that about 10,000 black Tulsans were left homeless. There were also reports of rich white residences being invaded by the armed rioters in search of black servants.

Comment: Similar: in 1906, shortly after the San Francisco earthquake, there was a string of arson attacks in California in which Chinese communities were destroyed. One example was in Pacific Grove: https://www.sfgate.com/news/article/Monterey-excavation-reveals-Chinese-fishing-3247099.php

Comment: This excerpt details anti-Chinese murder and extortion from 1850s to the 1906 Ben mentioned. https://books.google.com/books?id=eTMehY6QRGgC&pg=PA182&lpg=PA182&dq=chinese+laundromat+early+united+states+burning It is page 182 from "Making of the American West: People and Perspectives
edited by Peter Mancall, Benjamin Heber Johnson"

Huge irony with the laundromats is at that time laundry took months as it was considered womens work and was shipped overseas. The Chinese were literally making their lives better as they burned them trying to run them out.

Comment: Wow, what a lovely country to live in.

Answer (score 44):

Yes. In San Francisco, 1849, a gang called the "Hounds" [looted and destroyed residences in the district of Little Chile](https://books.google.com/books?id=83ShCgAAQBAJ&lpg=PA61&ots=MP38GRS9jU&dq=%22chilecito%22%20hounds&pg=PA60#v=onepage&q&f=false):

> "The Chileans in large numbers are living in tents on the outskirts of town. About 10 o'clock at night the Hounds made an assault upon them, tore down more than a dozen of their tents, broke open their chests, stole their money, tore their clothing and scattered their property, and fired upon them with pistols intending to kill as many as they could."

By the next night 17 suspects had been detained by a volunteer police force, a forerunner of the famous [Committees of Vigilance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/San_Francisco_Committee_of_Vigilance).

(There has been debate in the comments about whether the episode was a "riot". This was actually one of the criminal charges brought by prosecutor Hall McAllister. Here is the Alta California's reporting on the charge of Riot from August 2, 1849:

[image: Alta California]

Secondary sources also calling the event a riot include Soulé's "Annals of San Francisco", Ellison's "A Self-Governing Dominion", and Monaghan's "Chile, Peru, and the California Gold Rush of 1849", which devotes a whole chapter to what it calls "The Anti-Chilean Riot".)

Comment: How is that a riot?

Comment: @pipe, riot, n 1: a public act of violence by an unruly mob.

Comment: A named gang executing a planned action is not an unruly mob.

Comment: Oh, I disagree, but if you don't like definition 1, try number 2: a state of disorder involving group violence.

Comment: While a riot is a state of disorder involving group violence, a state of disorder involving group violence is not necessarily a riot. The following are examples of a state of disorder involving group violence that are not generally considered riots: a battle, a skirmish, an ambush, a terrorist attack, a robbery, a gang war etc.

Comment: Please see my last edit adding authorities that described these actions as "riot".